# How to disable C++ .pdb generation when using makefiles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, pdb-files

We have several compiler flags included during our build -

```
cl -c -MD -nologo -Od  /Zc:forScope /Zm800 -EHca  -Foemaildoc.obj ...
```

... followed by several other unrelated flags (mostly -IC). I'm trying to figure out why we're still building .pdb files? Our project is through VS2010, so is there a setting somewhere in the IDE that I need to turn off?

### Edit 1:

Turns out this was an environment setting that was getting invoked.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505322/disable-c-pdb-generation-from-the-ide

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `pdb` files are generated is that you build your program with `/ZI` or `/Zi` (for C/C++). Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info.

To disable it, you can set it in VS:

1. Compiler: `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Debug Information Format > make it empty`
2. Linker: `Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging> Generate Debug Info > set to No`

---

**Edit:** *However, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910066/2589776), you should only do this if you are sure you don't need them.*

It might be better to keep the PDB files, and just copy over the files that you need.

Before changing the setting, [please read this](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know).

Comment: Clearly, the line above has none of the switches you mention.

Comment: @ctote Please list all your compiler options. I'm pretty sure it will.

Comment: I removed my downvote - the option was there during our build script, but not during the manual build (which is where I pulled the flags). Sorry, the issue was eebkac here.